# jmeter run part of thread groups sequentually

Tags: jmeter, threadgroup

I've got quite complex jmeter test plan that prepares data and save pre-conditions to properties that next thread groups use. So I CANNOT disable "Run thread groups consecutively" and split this onto 2 different plans. But I need to emulate different users' behavior and those thread groups differ by Number of threads and queries. 
Is there any way to launch selected thread groups sequentially without breaking preparation on a regular basis?

[image: Test plan thread groups]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will try to do that via setUp Thread Groups/ Thread Groups / TearDown Thread Groups and without Run consecutively

Comment: It's not an answer but a comment

Comment: Yes, but that did help :)